# Renaming folders from list

Tags: list, batch-file, directory

I am needing some assistance trying to figure out this batch file.
I am trying to rename the folders inside of the "TARGETFOLDER" from the "TARGETFOLDER.txt"

Here is my Batch File:

```
   for /d %%f in (TARGETFOLDER\*) do rename "%%f" TARGETFOLDER.txt
```

For testing purposes I have 1 folder inside TARGETFOLDER named TEST1.
I have the TARGETFOLDER.txt with 1 line that says TEST2, in work directory.
What I am ending up with is the folder inside the TARGETFOLDER is getting renamed to "TARGETFOLDER.txt" and not renamed to TEST2.

Any Assistance would be Greatful!

Comment: To read the text file use a [`for /F` loop](http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html). Nevertheless, you need to specify how to associate the new folder names in the lines of the text files with the found folders...

Comment: Yes!I was just looking at using csv file for just that.  I better start reading more because I don't even know where to start with that.